# How to execute shell script in jenkins Active Choice Parameter so that I can get the dynamic inputs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I tried fetching present working directory using below script in Active Choice Parameter in Jenkins but it's not giving any output. Also the fallback script is not getting called

```
def command = "pwd"
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()              
def output = proc.in.text
def exitcode = proc.exitValue()
def error = proc.err.text
println "${output}"
```

Comment: Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This script will run well with script console in Jenkins at http://jenkins-url/script but in active choice you don't need to print the output instead you can return the output from script so parameter will get the value.

```
def command = "pwd"
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()              
def output = proc.in.text
def exitcode = proc.exitValue()
def error = proc.err.text
return [output]
```

in jenkins pipeline you can print the value of the parameter as below -
suppose you have defined the parameter name in active choice is param1 and you can get the value in pipeline as below -

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('sample active choice') {
            steps {
                echo "Param value is ${param1}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```